# Does this result about sylow subgroups hold for infinite groups? (Rotman excercise)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $P$ be a Sylow subgroup of $G$. Let $N(P) \leq H $. Prove $H=N(H)$. Did Rotman omit that $G$ is finite?

This is exercise 4.11 in the fourth edition.

> Does it hold for infinite groups also?

Edit: I wrote a letter to Rotman and he told me I could assume the group is finite.

Comment: Does he talk about Sylow $p$-subgroups in infinite groups at all?

Comment: Rotman is obviously talking of finite groups here, as otherwise the meaning of Sylow subgroup would be very twisted (one can do that by extending the naturals and stuff). Yet it is understandble the confusion since Rotman all the times reminds the reader that a group is finite.

Comment: @Timbuc: I think your comment should be an answer.

Comment: A sylow p subgroup os a maximal p subgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotman is obviously talking of finite groups here, as otherwise the meaning of Sylow subgroup would be very twisted (one can do that by extending the naturals and stuff).

Yet the confusion is  understandble since Rotman all the times reminds the reader that a group is finite.

Comment: A sylow p subgroup is a maximal p- subgroup un Rotman.

Comment: @JorgeFernández In Rotman and everywhere else, Jorge. Why do you remark this?

Comment: Because finiteness has nothing to do with maximality. A p-subgroup is one un which every element has order power of p.

Comment: Infinite **Sylow** subgroups, in order to keep some of the qualities they have in finite groups, would also need to be conjugated, at least. If we define Sylow subgroup as maximal $\;p$- subgroups *wrt inclusion among $\;p$- subgroups*, and if there is a **finite** conjugation class of these subgroups, then indeed they all are conjugate. I guess that otherwise they could be not (or even not isomorphic), but I can't provide a counter example.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked if it was true with the other definicion. I was fairly sure it should be finite. Bit I want to know whether it holds un general ot not.

Comment: Oh, sorry I asked what I want to ask. But for an answer  to be definitive it needs to have certainty. Timbuc is just giving his opinion.

Comment: @Jorge Well, *unless* I am Rotman or I could ask him directly, I can't see how  could I give "certainty"...

Comment: proving it is false without the finiteness condition.

Comment: The problem is I need to be certain. It's part of my homework and I can't prove it without the finiteness condition. But I appreciate your help. I cannot contact my teacher and in case he wants the general case I will lose points.

Comment: Well, you can try that @JorgeFernández . Infinite groups, and more particularly infinite Sylow subgroups, aren't my thing.

Comment: You can try to contact directly Rotman, at Illinois university in Urbana. yet both because of the chapter in the book and because how Sylow subgroups are treated there, I'd bet my weekly allowance that either we're talking about finite groups (90% sure), or else the claim is *also* true for the infinite case.

Comment: Rotman's proof of Sylow generalizes to infinite groups.  See the end of these notes for more information: https://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math131b/Sylow.pdf